# What can I accomplish with a Juju charm?

Tags: juju

I have seen this question: [What is Juju? What is a Juju Charm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80330/what-is-a-juju-charm)

I have more questions.

1. Which services can be deployed using juju charm?
2. Can lxc-containers be deployed using juju charm?
3. Are juju charms like SMF (Service Management Facility like in Solaris)?

   [(So, a charm tells juju how to manage a service) @Sergey Answer)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80330/what-is-a-juju-charm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can deploy any service juju has a charm for, here's the [list of charms](http://jujucharms.com/solutions).
2. Not really, juju can use LXC containers to deploy charms, we call this the "local provider". So for example if I want to test deploying MySQL and Wordpress on your laptop juju can use LXC so that you can deploy them both on the laptop as if you were deploying them on EC2 or OpenStack. It would make a container for each one.
3. [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com) is like SMF. There's no real analogy for juju that I can think of. It's been called "apt for the cloud", except that instead of managing whatever service on individual machines you manage just the service and it manages that over a set of machines, so in that case it's more of a deployment tool than a lower level tool like Upstart or SMF.