# What is exactly Juju?

Tags: canonical, juju

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a Juju Charm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80330/what-is-a-juju-charm)

I am a sys-admin and I heard about Juju from Canonical. What is it and what could be his utility for someone like me ?

Comment: Juju - and Juju Charm are closely related terms - the definition of Juju is in the linked Q&A.